# Matplotlib figures not changing interactively - Canopy Ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to use the ipython in canopy with matplotlib to prepare graphs (backend set to qt). I wrote the following code line by line int the terminal

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
s = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
```

after the second line I can see the figure being made. However after the third line I do not see the sub plot being created. However If I print fig, the sub-plot is can be seen both inline and in the figure window created. This sub-plot also magically appears if I try to zoom. Similar thing happens every time i plot something on the figure. The old version is displayed till I either print the figure or if i try to modify the view using the GUI tools. This is really annoying. It would be great if someone could tell me where the problem is.

Edit: Tried using fig.show() which does not work. Also when I use the plt.plot() directly, there seems to be no problem. The problem comes only when i use fig or any of its subplots

Answer (score 0):

type:
`fig.show()` when you need to update it.

Comment: Works for me with python 2.5.4, python 2.6.6 or ipython 0.13.1 under 2.6.6 - All I have had time to test.

Answer (score 0):

you should try using **fig.canvas.draw()** instead of using **fig.show()** when it comes to interactive plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.show()
## should show an empty figure ##
s = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
fig.show()
## things stay unchanged ##
fig.canvas.draw()
## things should be OK now ##
```